# Toggle on off click state after function execution jquery

Tags: jquery, html, button, mouseevent, toggle

i'm having a problem with a button's behavior. The button toggles on mouseover mouseleave state, and when clicked fires another function that slides a text that is animated in typewriter fashion.

What i would like to do is to disable/toggle the click state while animation is playing (you can see what happens with the string if you click more than once) and re-enable it once the animation has completed.

I searched for similar questions and already tried to implement some of that logic but can't seem to make it work. Maybe the problem is not the button but the way the string is executed, i would really appreciate any help with this,  it has been driving me crazy!

Sincere thanks and best regards!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btn-icon').on("mouseover mouseleave", expand);

$('#btn-icon').on("click", function (evt) {
    $('#btn-icon').off("mouseover mouseleave", expand);
    expandAll();
});
```

});

```
function expand(evt) {
$('#btn-icon').toggleClass("expand");
$('#btn-text').fadeToggle('2000');

console.log('expand');
```

}

full code/jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/shinobisan/vCVVZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to indicate if the animation is currently running ([see the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vCVVZ/2/)):

```
var isActive = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn-icon').off("mouseover mouseleave", expand);
    if( !isActive) {isActive = true; expandAll(); }
});

 // and inside expandAll when animation is done, 
 // you set the isActive to false again.
 $.each(para_text.split(''), function (i, letter) {
    setTimeout(function () {
    }, 100 * i, function () {
        isActive = false;
    });
});
```

Canceling the animations with .stop is also a good idea.

Comment: use `mouseenter` instead.

Comment: That's works beautifully! only it wasn't returning false on last function, maybe because of loop? so i placed it in function that gets called when div slides up and now it works!! [link](http://jsfiddle.net/shinobisan/vCVVZ/3/) Thanks so much!

Comment: @Buljan is right, mentioning the mouseenter, replace your mouseover with mouseenter since you use mouseleave.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @Buljan,@Michel,  i was unaware of that distinction, from what i can gather the mouseenter differs from mouseover in that it is triggered only by selected element and not by it's children. (please correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: @user3330769 yes, it just that, so it would be better to use mouseover/mouseout or mouseenter/mouseleave otherwise there could be some strange side-effects, depending on the fact if you have children elements or not.

Comment: @Michel, i understand, and thanks again for all your help, for now i will try to create a loop for all buttons since i plan to have more than one. I've been looking into arrays but maybe there is simpler method? also for looping the divs i was thinking of using .each and .child methods for iterating the child elements of each button which would share the same classes, any suggestions how to approach this?, thanks!